# "Perder la chaveta" primer uso de esta expresión

Tags: uso-de-palabras, modismos, historia

"***Perder la chaveta***" = "P*erder la cabeza*" o "*Perder el juicio*"

Al principio no entendía mucho la relación entre una cosa con la otra y me puse a investigar. El parecer la palabra "*chaveta*" proviene del latín "*clavis*" que en italiano es "*ciave*" (se pronuncia "*chiave*" en español) cuyo diminutivo es "*ciavetta*" o llave pequeña.

Así la expresión deriva de decir "*perder la ciavetta*" o "*perder la llavecita*" que pasó a significar "*perder la llave de la realidad*", es decir, perder la noción de lo que es real e irreal.

La pregunta es:

**¿Alguien tiene la primera referencia de un escritor español que utilice esta expresión?**

Estoy buscando un uso por escrito de esta expresión. Supongo que aparecerá en alguna obra de teatro o una comedia.

Comment: Según el diccionario, "chaveta" viene efectivamente del italiano "ciavetta" o "chiavetta", aunque en español nunca ha tenido el significado de "llavecita". La palabra ya existía en el siglo XVII, aunque por entonces se escribía "chabeta", y hacía referencia a un pestillo o tipo de pestillo, más que a una llave. En algún momento la palabra pasó a ser sinónimo de "cabeza" (cuarta acepción actual), podría ser interesante saber cómo se llegó a ese significado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La primera aparicion que muestra el [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) es de mediados del s. XVIII:

> Tiene vd. razon de decir que el conde de Fuentes **pierde la chaveta**, cuando se le toca la tecla de jesuitas: yo lo experimento cada correo (...)
>
> <sub>José Nicolás de Azara, *Cartas de Azara al ministro Roda en 1768*, 1768.</sub>

Hay otra aparición, que el CORDE data entre 1730 y 1791, y que corresponde a una recopilación de poemas escritos por Tomas de Iriarte y publicados en 1805; pero dado que esta persona no nació hasta 1750, dudo mucho que sus poemas sean anteriores al texto que te indico de 1768.

---

CORDE es una recopilación, hecha por la RAE, de miles de textos escritos en español durante los "últimos" 1300 años. Te recomiendo que la añadas a tu caja de herramientas lingüísticas particular.

Comment: Eso haré. Lo cierto es que es curioso que lleve tanto tiempo usándose.